# Mysql group by Regex match value

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to figure out how to group my results from a Mysql query by the value of one of my columns. The database / table in question is the WordPress options table, which has the following columns:

- option_id
- option_name
- option_value
- autoload

I have an [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com) repeater field set up to hold a series of states and cities. Unfortunately, I have over 5000 cities listed, and ACF works by using a single query for each city, resulting in ridiculously high query counts and page loads. I'm trying to optimize my functions using direct DB calls to reduce the number of queries, and I'm almost there, I just can't figure out how to group my data appropriately. What I'm trying to do right now is get all of the states and their associated info from the DB in a single call. I have the following values I'm trying to get:

- State Name
- State Abbreviation
- State Slug

ACF stores these values in the options table, each in its own entry with slightly matching option names. For each state I add, three entries are added to the options table with the following option_name values:

- options_states_0_state_name
- options_states_0_state_abbreviation
- options_states_0_state_slug

The numbers increment up as more states are added. I need to get all the info for every state (we have 51 listed in our database, each one has three entries, for a total of 153 records I need to retrieve). I managed to set up a query as follows which gets the info, but it doesn't group it:

```
select option_name, option_value from wp_options where
option_name REGEXP '^options_states_.+_state_.+$';
```

I need to group my entries by the number in the middle of the entry (0 in this case), instead of just listing them in order. I want to have 51 results returned instead of 153, and each result should be an array containing state name, state abbreviation, and state slug. How can I group my values by the number in the middle of a value name? I've attached a screenshot of the DB structure and query results for more clarity.

[image: screenshot of current query results]

EDIT for clarity:

At the end of the day, I want to have a structure like this returned:

```
array(
  array(
    'options_states_0_state_name' => 'Alabama',
    'options_states_0_state_abbreviation' => 'AL',
    'options_states_0_state_slug' => 'al',
  ),
  array(
    'options_states_1_state_name' => 'Alaska',
    'options_states_1_state_abbreviation' => 'AK',
    'options_states_1_state_slug' => 'ak',
  ),
  etc...
)
```

each individual state should have it's own array containing the three values above, grouped by the number that appears in the middle of the key. I don't mind if it's a standard array instead of associative either. I just need everything to be grouped correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem. For anybody in the future that may run into this, I ended up finding out that you can't return a match value from a REGEXP expression natively in MySQL. Instead, I had to use string comparison functions to trim out the value I needed, and then ran a few inner joins to get each value I needed in the format required. Here's the SQL code I used:

```
SELECT 
first.option_value as state_name,
second.option_value as state_abbreviation,
third.option_value as state_slug
from tsd_cm_options as first
inner join tsd_cm_options as second on second.option_name = CONCAT('options_states_',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(first.option_name, 'options_states_',  -1), '_state_name', 1),'_state_abbreviation')
inner join tsd_cm_options as third on third.option_name = CONCAT('options_states_',SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(first.option_name, 'options_states_',  -1), '_state_name', 1),'_state_slug')
where first.option_name like "options_states_%_state_name"
```

It's a bit messy, but it gets the job done and runs fairly quickly. Here's a screenshot of the output:

[image]